# Rails: NoMethodError in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and I've been wandering aimlessly around stackoverflow trying to find a solution to my problem but can't seem to figure it out. I'm doing chapter 10 of Michael Hartl's tutorial and when I try to view the profile of a specific user the localhost:3000 page I get the following error messages:

```
"NoMethodError in Users#show"
```

followed by

```
"undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass".
```

The source is listed as the first line of my show.html.erb file but I can't see anything wrong with the code.

The home page works fine and the users index is viewable but beyond that it doesn't work. I understand that this could mean that the @user object is nil but I'm not sure how to fix this. My Rspec tests are also failing hard - any help would be greatly appreciated.

My users_controller.rb file:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # Arranges for a particular method to be called before the given actions.
  before_filter :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,      only:  :destroy # Restricts the destroy action to admins.

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    # def signed_in_user
    #   unless signed_in?
    #     store_location
    #     redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    #   end
    # end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

My show.html.erb file:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

    # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

Comment: Why you have your show action as a private method in the controller ?

Comment: Thanks so much Khaled! I don't know why I put the show action there - stupid - I just added it to the end of the sequence. Just moved it out of the private method and now the tests are passing so thanks heaps! Phew...been agonising over this one...

Answer (score 0):

Here @user is nil. Because there is no record with the id (params[:id]). Thats why this error is coming.

```
 <h1>
 <%= gravatar_for @user %>
 <%= !@user.nil? @user.name : "" %>
 </h1>


         It will check whether the @user having any record, if its having it will display it's name else it will display empty.
```

Comment: Great Hauleth. We can use that andand also

Comment: @vijikumar: The `NoMethodError` will happen in multiple places and your fix will only help with one of them.

Comment: Yes @Koraktor. You are right.. I have given just a solution for current error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't find a user:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

does apparently return `nil`.

Please check that a user with the given ID exists. Additionally, you should make your actions fail safely when no object(s) are found:

```
<% if @user.nil? %>
  <% provide(:title, 'Not found') %>
  No user with that ID has been found.
<% else %>
  <!-- Contents of your current show.html.erb -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm navigating to the user profile page through the user index - so clicking on an existing user. If the query doesn't find a user then how do I alert it to an existing user?

Comment: Thanks heaps for all the responses! Just a stupid mistake. Solved!